# Replacing loops for entering migrations in migration matrices stored in a 3 dimensional array

Tags: r

I have a list of number of migrations (`migrations`) from one state (A, B or C) to another for two dates (2014 or 2015 in `obsDates`). I want to input these migrations in a 3-dimensional array (`mgrMat`) containing the migration matrices for every date. In order to do so, I use two loops (see code below). Is there a way to get rid of these loops (in reality the code is a bit more complex and the loops make one really lose overview)? I don't see how it can be done with `apply`.

```
obsDates =  c("2014", "2015")

migrations = data.frame(obsDate = c("2014", "2015", "2015", "2014", "2015"),
                        t1 = c("A", "A", "B", "C", "C"),
                        t2 = c("A", "B", "C", "A", "B"),
                        number = c(1, 8, 8, 10, 5),
                        stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

mgrMat = array(0, 
               dim = c(3, 3, 2), 
               dimnames = list(c("A", "B", "C"), c("A", "B", "C"), obsDates))

for (i in 1:length(obsDates)){

  migrationsDate = migrations[migrations$obsDate == obsDates[i],]

  for (j in 1:nrow(migrationsDate)){

    mgrMat[migrationsDate$t1[j], migrationsDate$t2[j], i] = migrationsDate$number[j]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is easy using the reshape2 package:

```
library(reshape2)
mgrMat1 <- acast(migrations, t1 ~ t2 ~ obsDate, value.var = "number", fill = 0)
all.equal(mgrMat, mgrMat1)
#[1] TRUE
```